# calculate median, average using hadoop spark1.6 dataframe, Failed to start database 'metastore_db'

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hadoop2, median, hivecontext, apache-spark-1.6

spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0
1. using SQLContext
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1. import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
2. val sqlctx = new SQLContext(sc)
3. import sqlctx._

4. val df = sqlctx.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferScheme","true").option("delimiter",";").option("header","true").load("/user/cloudera/data.csv")
5. df.select(avg($"col1")).show() // this works fine
6. sqlctx.sql("select percentile_approx(balance,0.5) as median from port_bank_table").show()
   or 
   sqlctx.sql("select percentile(balance,0.5) as median from port_bank_table").show()
   // both are not working , getting the below error

   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function percentile_approx; line 0 pos 0
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:65)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:65)
7. using HiveContext
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   so tried using hive context
   scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
   import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

scala> val hivectx = new HiveContext(sc)
18/01/09 22:51:06 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
hivectx: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@5be91161

scala> import hivectx._
import hivectx._

```
getting the below error 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@be453c4, 
see the next exception for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any percentile_approx,percentile function in Spark aggregation functions.It does not seem like this functionality is built into the Spark DataFrames. For more information please follow this [How to calculate Percentile of column in a DataFrame in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668343/how-to-calculate-percentile-of-column-in-a-dataframe-in-spark/37777447#37777447)
I hope so it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't think so, it should work, for that you should save the table in 
dataFrame using saveAsTable. Then you will be able to run your query using 
HiveContext.

df.someDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite) 
              .format("parquet")
              .saveAsTable("Table_name")

# In my case "mode" is working as mode("Overwrite")

hivectx.sql("select avg(col1) as median from Table_name").show()

It will work.
```